# Issue: connect rest application with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra 3.11 docker image for my application. But I am getting below. Can someone suggest a fix here

[image]

Comment: Please reformat your question correctly. Post your code, explain the error, and explain what confuses you about it

Answer (score 1):

**Enable Thrift server of Cassandra**

The error means that JanusGraph can't connect to cassandra with thrift, So you have to enable thrift on cassandra.

Use the below command to enable thrift

```
nodetool enablethrift
```

Comment: Can you connect to cassandra with cqlsh  and execute simple query ?

Comment: yes I can connect to it and execute quries.  My microservice able to connect to it and all works fine initially. But some times I see this error. Is it because of data it writes or some network issue.